# Connecting botpress to external postgres DB server over SSL

Tags: javascript, postgresql, botpress

I need to connect botpress to my external DB server which runs on a separate server from botpress. 
The connection is over SSL as this is required by the DB server and cannot be switched off.

I can connect from the vps where botpress runs to the DB server with a python script.

Using the same string for DATABASE_URL=postgres:// gets me the error: `no pg_hba.conf for host... SSL off`

Where can I enable SSL DB connection in botpress?

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening here is that your client first tries to connect over SSL, and gets rejected for some reason.  It then automatically tries again with SSL off, and gets rejected because the pg_hba requires ssl.  The client reports only this second error to you (or it reports both and you only notice the 2nd one), which is not the most useful one.

If you set PGSSLMODE=require or equivalent on the client, it should stop after the first try and report the first error in a clearer manner.

You also might find more details in the server log file.  The messages sent to the unauthenticated (presumably hostile) client can be intentionally vague.